# Wicket: How to use Map instead of PropertyModel?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

We user Wicket 6 and usually are fine with POJO objects and PropertyModel to access model attributes.
Now instead of a POJO I want to use a Map, how can I do that?

Instead of

```
form.add(new TextField<String>("fieldName", new PropertyModel<String>(pojo, "fieldName")));
```

I want to use something like

```
form.add(new TextField<String>("fieldName", new MapModel<String>(map, "field.name")));
```

Is there any Wicket class to do that?

Comment: Isn't that what you want: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/model/util/MapModel.html ?

Comment: That'd expose a Mode which is a map itself. I need a model which represents just one value from the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following should do the job:

```
form.add(new TextField<String>("fieldName", new PropertyModel<String>(map, "keyName")));
```

Comment: Although this isn't documented very clearly but `PropertyModel` (or rather, the underlying `PropertyResolver` does work with maps as you'd expect it to be. It also recognizes `length` or `size` of an array: `new PropertyModel<Integer>( new String[5], "size" ).getObject() == 5`.